# [Mouse-Pointer]-Trap

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

The [mouse-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouse-pointer), [mouse-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouse-position), [mouse-cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouse-cursor) and [cursor-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursor-position) tags have 32, 102, 137 and 226 questions respectively.

They seem to be used occasionally in combination with other mouse-event related tags, but are often specific enough that no other tag would suitably describe them. I propose a merge of these low-traffic tags, to group possibly related questions and help users find answers.

Comment: I wouldn't mix cursor-"x" with mouse-"x"; they aren't exactly the same thing.

Comment: I think we agree that nearly no users will ever be questioning the physical position of their mouse, but I see your point that there may be users who are interested in mouse movement rather than the actual cursor.